# Convert querys SQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

How can I convert this for PostgreSQL please?

```sql
SELECT flight_number,
       departure_airport,
       arrival_airport,
       departure_time,
       arrival_time,
       HOUR(arrival_time-departure_time)
FROM flights
HAVING HOUR(arrival_time-departure_time) < 2;
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  `HAVING` with no `GROUP BY` is quite suspicious.

Comment: In all databases, filtering is performed with WHERE, not HAVING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want flights that are less than 2 hours, then Postgres would interpret this as:

```
SELECT flight_number, departure_airport, arrival_airport, departure_time, arrival_time, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM arrival_time - departure_time)
FROM flights 
WHERE arrival_time < departure_time + INTERVAL '2 hour';
```

This is not exactly what your code does.  Actually, without knowing the source database and the datatypes for the columns, it is hard to say what it is really doing.